# Creating a blog without a CMS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, content-management-system

I'm working with a local business to redo their website. I've been a huge WordPress fan in the past and originally planned to built their site on the CMS; however, due to some budget restrictions I think I may need to build the site from scratch with Node, Express, and Mongo.

Here's my question:

Is it a bad idea to build blog posts as simple HTML pages, store the content in mongo, and host them on the site? Or is this much more complicated than I'm imagining? I'm really focused on allowing my website to maintain its original SEO value and continue to thrive in search engines, and I know WordPress takes care of many SEO quirks, which is why I'm asking here.

I've looked at some CMS's like Keystone, but my time frame doesn't allow me to dive deep into learning a new framework at the moment.

Any advice and help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Creating it from scratch will require a not-insignificant amount of coding. Sure, you *can*, but it'll take some time, and the result will not be tried-and-tested. Using an existing system so as not to reinvent the wheel is probably the easier solution by far, even though it might cost a bit

Comment: @CertainPerformance Right -- coding it would take a while. I don't think I'll be doing it for this project anymore. By chance, do you know where I could find some resources for how to code an SEO-optimized blog from the ground up (preferably Node, Express, and Mongo)? Although I can't do it today, I certainly have to learn how now that I've spent 4 hours trying to figure out if it's possible. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronMarsden If you find any way of doing it just let us know.